# CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake with nsclient++

Tags: ssl, nrpe, icinga

I'm using `NRPE` (v2.15) on my Icinga-Server to check the **memory usage** on a
windows host with `nsclient++` (v0.4.3.143).

Unluckily I always get the same error message when I try to check it:

```
./check_nrpe -H host01 -p 5666 -c CheckMem -a MaxWarn=95% MaxCrit=98% ShowAll type=physical
CHECK_NRPE: Error - Could not complete SSL handshake.
```

Comment: If i add "-n" to the command i get another error message: CHECK_NRPE: Received 0 bytes from daemon.  Check the remote server logs for error messages.

Comment: And the nsclient log contains?

Comment: can you add your nrpe.cfg here?? port No, allowed host, we need to check.